# Internal server error on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, installation

I just reinstalled my webserver and found myself having an error that I know nothing about :(

I'm using apache 2, I'm assuming my mysql environment is well installed, although I have no clue on how to check that. I just unzipped phpmyadmin 4.5 on the www/ folder, created the config folder , gave it the right rights, moved my config.ini.php inside, but whenever i try to acces domainname/phpMyAdmin or domainname/phpMyAdmin/setup/ i'm getting this:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domainname and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

And here are the apache2 logs:

[Sun Aug 23 19:11:23 2015] [error] [client 79.91.191.99] SoftException in  Application.cpp:350: UID of script "/home/MGC/www/phpMyAdmin/index.php" is smaller than min_ uid

[Sun Aug 23 19:11:23 2015] [error] [client 79.91.191.99] Premature end of script hearders: index.php

Comment: change the user and group of your files to match the user of the webserver process, `apache2` most likely you unzipped as root or something

Comment: i'm not very familiar with linux right now, i used a simple chmod -R o+rwx and i cannot acces by ftp anymore, i'm affraid i broke something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following in ssh terminal

1. in the phpmyadmin root dir to fix permissions

   ```
   chmod -R 0755 *
   ```
2. to find the apache user

   ```
   ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd|www)'
   ```
3. outside the phpmyadmin dir to set ownership

   ```
   chown -R www-data:www-data *
   ```

`www-data` is the apache user on ubuntu, on your distro might be different

Comment: I might have messed up when trying to fix by myself, i now have no rights to access the server via my web brower at home. I'm still able to create and delete files via FTP using MGC user i have a little index.php file at www/, blank, to test if i can acces it out, but it gives me a standard 403 error

Comment: if you have FTP access, then delete all phpmyadmin files, upload the zip again by ftp and un-zip from cpanel

Comment: Here are the permission setting at the moment in www/ :http://puu.sh/jLMtN/240cab73b4.png (i'm logged in as MGC)

Comment: I can't acces domainname/ at all, it is not even phpmyadmin anymore it's the whole thing :/

Comment: 403 forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: yes it was indeedly www-data as i'm under ubuntu 7.5

Comment: Maybe i can't acces because the whole directory is under www-data's control?

Comment: when you say you cannot access is it over ftp or via browser, or both?

Comment: I can't acces via browser, but i thin i'll just erase the www/ and make another one while logged under MGC

Comment: That solution didn't work, everything is owned by MGC but i still cant access my website. I wonder what did i do wrong

Comment: hey @MorganFouque let's continue this on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87799/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-32169407-internal-server-error-on-phpmyadmin

Comment: I sadly can't speak there, i need 20 reputation in order to do so, but if you want you can add me on skype @Morganeon